# What is the difference between 혹 잘못이 and 잘못이?

Tags: word-choice, adjective

I get that `잘못` is `a wrong` or perhaps `wrong doing/sin/fault/misbehavior/error` (whatever) and that `이` is a subject particle.

**But how does `혹` alter that noun?**

I know the story of `혹부리 할아버지`, and so, I know that a literal `혹` is a lump (on the body perhaps).  Of course, 혹 sometimes also might refer to a cancerous lump.  **But I'm stumped as to if `혹` in this adjective use makes *the wrong* less or more drastic or modifies it in some other nuance that I wouldn't expect.**

Are there other uses where `혹` might alter a meaning or be heard colloquially?

---

*For any who might want an example of where I found this usage here is the sentence*

> ***혹 잘못이*** 있어도 용서하여 그 사람을 하나님께로 이끌어 변화의 길로 갈 수 있습니다

---

### What is the difference/nuance between `잘못이` and `혹 잘못이`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"혹 잘못이 있어도"는 아래 문장들과 의미가 같습니다:

- 혹시 잘못이 있어도
- 혹시나 잘못이 있어도
- 혹여 잘못이 있어도
- 혹여나 잘못이 있어도
- ...

일상 생활에서는 보통 '혹'이라고 혼자 쓰이기 보다는, '혹시', '혹여나' 등으로 더욱 자주 쓰입니다.

Answer (score 2):

혹

> 1. a wen, a lump, a bump, a swelling, a protuberance
> 2. a hump
> 3. maybe, if (=혹시 = ~이/가 ~도 = ~이/가 ~다 해도)

***혹** 잘못이 있어도 .. = **혹시** 잘못이 있어도 .. = 잘못**이** 있어**도** .. = 잘못**이** 있**다** **해도** ..

They have the same meaning.

> 4. sometimes (=간혹, 이따금)

Here are more examples.

http://endic.naver.com/search_example.nhn?sLn=kr&examType=example&query=%ED%98%B9&pageNo=1